# WebSocket http.globalAgent.maxFreeSockets dont working Node.js

Tags: node.js, websocket

I have a custom implementation serwer websockets. Everything work fine but http.globalAgent.maxFreeSockets isnt not set to Infinity. Limit connection is 256 and if I fills connection (btw. flood attack) the number of vice versa to 0 value. Why not work maxFreeSockets?

Code:

```js
var http = require('http');
var https = require('https');
http.globalAgent.maxFreeSockets = Infinity;
var crypto = require("crypto");
function WebSocket(options) {
 "use strict";
 var self = this;
 var options = options || {};
 this.clients = [];
 this.server = options.ssl ? https.createServer(options) : http.createServer();
 this.server.setTimeout(30 * 1000 * 60);
 this.init(options);
}
WebSocket.prototype.init = function (options) {
 "use strict";
 var that = this;
 this.server.on('upgrade', function (req, socket, upgradeHead) {
  if(that.clients.length > 63)
   return;
  if (options.origin && req.headers['origin'] !== options.origin) {
   abortConnection(socket, 401, 'Unauthorized');
  };
  var uuid = "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11";
  var key = req.headers['sec-websocket-key'];
  var hash = require('crypto').createHash('sha1').update(key + uuid).digest('base64');
  var headers = ["HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols", "Upgrade: WebSocket", "Connection: Upgrade", "Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13", "Sec-WebSocket-Accept: " + hash];
  if (options.origin) {
   headers.push("Sec-WebSocket-Origin: " + req.headers['origin']);
  }
  socket.write(headers.concat('', '').join('\r\n'));
  that.clients.push(socket);
  if (that.onclient) {
   that.onclient(req, socket, true);
  }
  var self = this;
  self.buffer = new Buffer(0);
  socket.on("data", function (data) {
   if(data.length > 2008){
    return;
   }
   self.buffer = Buffer.concat([self.buffer, data]);
   if ((self.buffer[0] & 15) === 0x8) {
    if (!options.ssl) {
     that.clients.splice(that.clients.indexOf(socket), 1);
     if (that.onclient) {
      that.onclient(req, socket, false);
     }
     return;
    }
   }
   self._process();
  });
  socket.on('error', function () {
   socket.destroy();
  });
  socket.on('close', function () {
   that.clients.splice(that.clients.indexOf(socket), 1);
   if (that.onclient) {
    that.onclient(req, socket, false);
   }
  });
  self._process = function () {
   var data = self.buffer;
   if (data.length < 2) {
    return;
   };
   var index = 2;
   var opcode = data[0];
   var length = data[1] & 127;
   if (length === 126) {
    length = data.readUInt16BE(2);
    index = 4;
   } else if (length === 127) {
    length = data.readUInt32BE(6);
    index = 10;
   }
   if (data.length < index + 4 + length) {
    return;
   }
   var mask = data.slice(index, index + 4);
   index += 4;
   var payload = data.slice(index, index + length);
   payload = self.unmask(mask, payload);
   that.ondata(payload, opcode, socket);
   self.buffer = data.slice(index + length);
  };
  self.unmask = function (mask, data) {
   var payload = new Buffer(data.length);
   for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    payload[i] = mask[i % 4]^data[i];
   };
   return payload;
  }
  that.mask = function (data, opcode) {
   var payload = new Buffer(data);
   if (data.length <= 125) {
    data = new Buffer(payload.byteLength + 2);
    data[0] = opcode;
    data[1] = payload.byteLength;
    payload.copy(data, 2);
   } else if (data.length >= 126 && data.length <= 65535) {
    data = new Buffer(payload.byteLength + 4);
    data[0] = opcode;
    data[1] = 126;
    data.writeUInt16BE(payload.byteLength, 2);
    payload.copy(data, 4);
   } else {
    data = new Buffer(payload.byteLength + 10);
    data[0] = opcode;
    data[1] = 127;
    data.writeUInt32BE(0, 2);
    data.writeUInt32BE(payload.byteLength, 6);
    payload.copy(data, 10);
   };
   that.clients.forEach(function (client) {
    client.write(data);
   });
   payload = payload.slice(payload.length)
  }
 });
}
WebSocket.prototype.listen = function (port, cb) {
 this.server.listen(port, cb)
}
WebSocket.prototype.send = function (data, opcode) {
 this.mask(data, opcode);
}
function abortConnection(socket, code, name) {
 try {
  var response = ['HTTP/1.1 ' + code + ' ' + name, 'Content-type: text/html'];
  socket.write(response.concat('', '').join('\r\n'));
 } catch (e) {}
 finally {
  try {
   socket.destroy();
  } catch (e) {}

 }
}
module.exports = new WebSocket();
```

Comment: Are you sure that you can set globalAgent.maxFreeSockets value to Infinity? Also, you set maxFreeSockets only to http, I assume you should do it for https as well. The last thing, from documentation: 'maxFreeSockets Number Maximum number of sockets to leave open in a free state. Only relevant if keepAlive is set to true. Default = 256'. Given that keepAlive is false by default you should probably set it to true to have maxFreeSockets value working.

Comment: i set http.globalAgent.keepAlive = true;
https.globalAgent.keepAlive = true;
http.globalAgent.maxFreeSockets = Infinity;
https.globalAgent.maxFreeSockets = Infinity; but limit is still 256

Comment: Can you try to set it to some number greater than 256 instead of Infinity?

Comment: Limit still 256. Mayby is bug in nodejs

Comment: Can you please show how and where do you check maxFreeSockets value?

Comment: this.clients = []; and display count on new connection. If connection is more than 256 it is impossible to connect to